# How to cluster similar item together in a 2d Graph

Tags: algorithm

well I am not looking for how to draw items on 2d Graph, Its just a pictorial representation of what the expected output need to be

I have a list like

```
a=[]
b=['c','d','e']
c=['a','b','d']
d=['a']
e=['b','a']
l=['g','r','p']
g=['r']
r=['g']
p=['l']
```

now from above it is clear that b is pointing to c , d ,e 

a,b,c,d are closely linked , while the l,g,r,p are linked 

can any one tell me an algo ( keeping 2d Picture in mind) how these similar items can be  reprsented together.

Above is just an example.
The list will  be dynamically created

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What do you mean by closely linked and linked?

Comment: You may want to use adjacency matrix to represent your graph (if the graph is quite small).

Comment: actualy i am not using a adjancy matrix to represent my graph, I am using a linked list approch. I mean  A point to a list which contain the elements as you can see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you come across [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)? It has algorithms for various different forms of graph layout which I imagine would do a nice job of laying out your small example above. It also includes some simple GUIs to allow you to experiment with the different layouts it supports.

**Edit: in response to some clarifications:**

If you need to find dense subgraphs within your graph, even if it is fully connected, then you are looking for algorithms that find *communities* in networks. An example of a recently-developed algorithm doing such on large graphs (2 million+ nodes, representing a social network) efficiently can be found in [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CF8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fantipaedo.lip6.fr%2FT12%2Fcommunities.pdf&ei=Nd_iT4nFNuSa0QW1trCODQ&usg=AFQjCNEOH2XnD0ybsBQsxwY-96bJNvYynw&sig2=8opDu41Af5hFVXcPMp2-5Q).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i dont need any tool to get the output i am interested in the algo it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend Alex's answer, here is an example of graphviz use for your graph:

graph.dot:

```
digraph G
{
  b -> c;
  b -> d;
  b -> e;
  c -> a;
  c -> b;
  c -> d;
  d -> a;
  e -> b;
  e -> a;
  l -> g;
  l -> r;
  l -> p;
  g -> r;
  r -> g;
  p -> l;
}
```

Output of Graphviz:

[image: Example graph]

If you just want to know what are the clusters in your graph without drawing it, just use [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29#Computational_aspects).

Comment: The above output is good , i want to draw as well, what if there is also a link b/w d and g. I mean to say that the graph is fully connected . But some nodes like b,c,d,a,e are connected or highly coupled same with l,g,r,p while there is a limited number of connection b/w the two groups. How the above two clusters can be determined , when a connection is thier b/w two cluster( But is a loose connection means a single or two link)